# Why would a long running Task still block the UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to resolve a problem where my UI is being blocked and I don't understand why.

```
public Task AddStuff(string myID, List<string> otherIDs)
{
    Action doIt = () =>
    {
        this.theService.AddStuff(myID, otherIDs);
    };

    return Task.Factory.StartNew(doIt, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

If the list is long the call can take 30 seconds and the entire application becomes unresponsive (goes that washed out white in Windows 7).

Is there a different way to do this so it doesn't block the UI?

---

**Edit**

Ok, so there's a LOT of code around this I'm going to try to keep this pertinent. I did realize going back to the original code, that I had removed something that may have been important. Should I maybe use a different TaskScheduler than `TaskScheduler.Current`?

Also there are no Wait statements impeding any of this code, and the service doesn't interact with the UI.

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(objState =>
    {
        LoadAssets(objState);
    }, state, this.cancellationToken, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);
```

---

```
private void LoadAssets(object objState)
{
    LoadAssetsState laState = (LoadAssetsState)objState;

    List<string> assetIDs = new List<string>();

    for (int i = 0; i < laState.AddedMediaItems.Count; i++)
    {
        if (laState.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;

        string assetId = this.SelectFilesStep.AssetService.GetAssetId(laState.AddedMediaItems[i], laState.ActiveOrder.OrderID);

        assetIDs.Add(assetId);

    }

    if (laState.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        return;

    this.ApiContext.AddAssetToProduct(laState.ActiveOrder.OrderID, laState.ActiveProduct.LineID, assetIDs, laState.Quantity, laState.CancellationToken).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (laState.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            return;


        App.ApiContext.GetOrderDetails(laState.ActiveOrder.OrderID, false, laState.CancellationToken).ContinueWith(orderDetailsTask =>
        {
            if (laState.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                return;

            this.activeOrder = orderDetailsTask.Result;

            this.StandardPrintProductsStep.Synchronize(this.activeOrder);

        });
    });
}
```

---

```
public Task AddAssetToProduct(string orderID, string lineID, List<string> assetIDs, int quantity, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
{
    Action doIt = () =>
    {
        if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested())
            return;

        this.ordersService.AddAssetToProduct(orderID, lineID, assetIDs, quantity);
    };

    if (cancellationToken != null)
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(doIt, cancellationToken.Value, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, TaskScheduler.Current);
    else
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(doIt, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
```

---

**EDIT**

I have placed break points just before and after the service call and it is the service call that is blocking the UI, as opposed to any other line.

It sounds like there is no reason this should be blocking, so I think I'm just going to break the list down if it's long and make multiple calls. I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something here with my Task logic.

Comment: The root cause is not in the code shown. Can you show the caller of AddStuff?

Comment: Is the `this.theService.AddStuff(myID, otherIDs);` the same as `public Task AddStuff(string myID, List<string> otherIDs)` if so then you are ending up creating an infinite number of tasks due to an infinite recursion!

Comment: why don't you punch the UI when you are ready with full power. insteed of punching several little punches. these little punches also cause your UI to get responsive.

Comment: This is updating a progress bar, but it's not until the service call at the very end that the UI is blocked.

Comment: I'd figure out why this is blocking the UI thread instead of 'punting' by breaking it down into multiple steps.  For instance, have the action 1) just do a Thread.Sleep instead and 2) print the thread id to see if it's "1" - it sounds like TaskScheduler.Default is the better choice here, though?

Comment: @JamesManning I did a Thread.Sleep and confirmed that the UI does not block and the thread ID was not 1. As far as the punting goes, there are other UX reasons why to have each of these in different Tasks. The service can be called from other parts of the application.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a different way to do this so it doesn't block the UI?

This call, in and of itself, should not block the UI.  If, however, `theService.AddStuff` does some synchronization with the UI's SynchronizationContext, this could cause the UI to effectively be blocked by that call.

Otherwise, the problem is likely happening from outside of this function.  For example, if you call `Wait()` on the task returned from this method, in a UI thread, the UI thread will be blocked until this completes.

---

You probably want to use [TaskScheduler.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.default.aspx), not `TaskScheduler.Current`.  If this is being called within a Task that's scheduled on a TaskScheduler based on the UI thread, it will schedule itself on the UI thread.

Comment: No dice, using Default instead of Current behaves the same way

Comment: @JoshRusso Can you run this under Visual Studio's concurrency visualizer?  You can break and show exactly what's blocking the main thread that way...

Comment: @JoshRusso No - it's in the Analyze window - Launch Performance Wizard (VS 2010) - in VS 2012 it's Analyze->Concurrency->...  It's only in higher SKUs.  You can also just look at the threads window, but it doesn't always work quite right if a thread's blocked.

Comment: Ya, I don't think we have a high enough version for that.

Comment: Additionally, we're actually handing the code over next week and I'm pretty convinced that it's their API that is causing the blocking. So I just gave it the band aid of splitting the lists up and making a series of smaller calls.

Answer (score 0):

Wish I could put formatted code in a comment, but since I don't see how, adding this snippet as an answer.  This is the kind of approach I'd use to figure out whether the task is running on the UI thread or not (since you don't want it to) and have the action be something completely different (a simple thread.sleep).

```
var state = new object();
var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
var cancellationToken = cancellationTokenSource.Token;

var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(
    objState => { Console.WriteLine ("Current thread is {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId); Thread.Sleep(30); },
    state,
    cancellationToken,
    TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning,
    TaskScheduler.Current);

task.Wait();
```